# I want to Read, Write and Save the Excel file which I have added as a Resource in my Project. I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: excel, vb.net, resources

I want to open the resources file

```
Public Class Form1    
Public excelapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Public excelwb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Public excelws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

excelapp = New Excel.Application
excelapp.Visible = False
'To Open File
Using FileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
        FileDialog.Title = "Select your Excel file"
        FileDialog.Filter = "Microsoft Excel|*.xl*|All Files|*.*"
        FileDialog.ShowDialog()
        If FileDialog.FileName = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select File")
            GoTo jump
        End If
        'To Open Excel with the file chosen after clicking on Open
        excelwb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(My.Resources.check) 'This won't work because it gets Byte[] and not string.
        excelws = excelwb.Worksheets(1)
    End Using
jump:    
End Sub
End Class
```

After making some changes in the file, I'd also like to save it i.e the resources file must be updated. So the next time when I run my Application, it should have the updated the file. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You don't update resources. They are compiled into the binary code of the EXE. If you want to make changes then don't use a resource.

Comment: Only way would be to extract the resource to an actual file and then change that file. You can't change en embedded resource.